# Set java.library.path when running a test in Netbeans

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, junit

To set the java.library.path to run my Java application, I just change the "VM Options:" value in my project properties like I've shown here:

[image: How to set java library path in Netbeans]

However, the java.library.path is **not** set when running a test. How can I set it for testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netbeans 8.2 my generated project.properties file contains this comment:

```
# To set system properties for unit tests define test-sys-prop.name=value
```

So you can edit the file and add there:

```
test-sys-prop.java.library.path=/path/to/your/native/libs
```

I tested the value with the `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` and it seemed to work.

But anyway if you fail with setting the `java.library.path` property you can always use the `PATH` environemt variable on Windows systems or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Unix-like systems.

Hope this will help. Petr

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but what I needed was to be able to do this in a Netbeans Platform RPC project.  Getting my unit test to recognize external dll libraries would not work with the normal VM Options dialog because those run settings are controlled differently in RPC projects.  The location of the external libraries have to be in special release folders:

release/modules/lib/amd64 for x64 libraries and 
release/modules/lib/x86 for x86 libraries.

To tell the unit tests which folders I was using I set the project properties like:

[image: Project Properties]

My reference for learning this was here:

[Netbeans Formum Topic 13801](https://forums.netbeans.org/topic13801.html)